# How to set in Visual Studio to let C++/C codes run in only one thread to test the running time?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, visual-studio

My purpose is to fairly test the running time (Flops of different algorithms), and currently I am using clock() to record the time. Maybe, suggest any better time-record function?

But I don't know how to let codes run in only one thread? Also, in Visual Studio, I don't know choose which Runtime Library (Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Code Generation->Runtime Library) for my case.

Comment: Note that in MSVC the [`clock()` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e2ess30.aspx) is non-standard as it measures wall time.

Answer (score 1):

By default any executable runs in a single thread. Only if you explicitly use constructs such as `std::thread`, `std::async` or `std::future` your executable may use more than one thread.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at C++11 `std::chrono` to measure times which is a very comfortable and portable way to work with times/clocks.

If you implemented threads by using `std::thread` they will be created anyhow. The question is just if they are executed in parallel or sequential. This depends on your system. If you have more than one CPU core you can try to set your process to use only one CPU by calling

```
start /affinity 1 program.exe
```

but it might be ignored.

Comment: In older versions of Visual Studio (I think any before VS2015), std::chrono high_resolution clock is not high resolution, it's just the default 64hz ticker, [timeBeginPeriod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757624(v=vs.85).aspx) should speed up the ticker to 1000hz == 1 ms per cycle. [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx) should run at over 1 mega-hertz.

Comment: Be careful with QueryPerformanceCounter because Frequency of the CPU migth change over runtime which will cause very small or very big results.

Comment: I haven't had that issue with QueryPerformanceCounter. On an Intel 3770k 3.5 ghz cpu which goes up to 3.9ghz, QueryPeformanceCounter always returns a counter running at a bit over 3 mega-hertz on Windows 7, and ~3.5ghz on Windows XP.